# What is the expected result?

Tags: calculation-puzzle

I found the following puzzle through social media websites,

[image]

**What is the expected result?**

It seems to be easy. But, it needs concentration.

Comment: This is just mental calculation. I mean, (ROT13) gur nafjre vf guerr cyhf sbhe cyhf sbhe gvzrf svsgrra juvpu vf fvkgl-frira. **Edit:** Wait... one of 'em doesn't look right... oh! I see!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am a new member  to the community and I didn't know which kinds of puzzles should I share. So, I am really sorry. By the way, I  just found that this puzzle was discussed in the community before.

Comment: Well, whether it was discussed earlier or not, it does not mean this is a bad puzzle. 'Tis a good puzzle, in my opinion, but all I will say is that make sure to cite where you found this puzzle if it is not created by you. Apart from that, I enjoyed the puzzle, though most importantly, welcome to the **Puzzling Stack Exchange (Puzzling.SE)**! :D

Comment: Thanks for your notice. I cite where I found that puzzle.

Answer (score 3):

This is a poor question, because it requires a lot of assumptions and poorly defined variables.

> The answer might be $2 + 3 + 3 \times 11 = 38$. Or it might be QuantumTwinkie’s answer of 67 — go upvote their answer!!

The reason why I’ve

> Said 38 is because the shapes are all different. While the square inscribed in a pentagon inscribed in a hexagon is worth 15 as found by @QuantumTwinkie, the question only asks about a pentagon inscribed in a hexagon. We *may extrapolate* that the former was worth 15 to match the number of vertices; and so we *may assume* that the latter is worth 11, but really the variable is not defined. Next, the bananas were worth 4 above; but that was a banana graphic with 4 bananas. Our question has 3 bananas. We may assume once again that our variable is worth 3, but....yeah. Finally, the clock variable was worth 3, but its hands were at 3:00. Our variable has hands at 2:00, and so we may assume that our variable is worth 2......but we’ve really made 3 assumptions as to what the original creator of the post was thinking, and not actually had any definition for the variables we are using.

—————————

**Edit:** I’ve seen that

> OP has agreed that my answer of 38 is correct. Despite that, I’m leaving my explanation up anyway to hopefully stimulate puzzlers into thinking about rigorous definitions of variables and how these types of puzzles intentionally obfuscate that to confuse the general public.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your notice about the question. It is the correct answer. I am really sorry if it was a poor question. I am a new member in the site. I did not know which level of puzzels to provide.

Comment: @Eman: I’ve seen these kinds of puzzles on Facebook before. This is definitely not your fault — the puzzles are intentionally designed to confuse people (I’m sure people have seen the comments on them where the public will stand behind 17 different answers and everybody has an argument for why they’re right!) That being said, welcome to Puzzling.SE! I’m really glad that you contributed (you’ve submitted one more puzzle than I have, for example) and I hope that you enjoy being a part of this wonderful community! :)

Comment: Thanks so much. It is really a wonderful community. It is of my pleasure to join it.

Comment: Hey, you are nearly on $10k$ rep! :D

Comment: 10k +8 lol +1 :)